# Limit height HTML Table with fixed columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a large table which I would like to apply a max-height to, however I am having difficulty doing this since the leftmost column is set to be fixed in place (using absolute positioning).

When I give a max height to its container div, the absolutely positioned div spills over and looks terrible. HTML looks roughly like this

```
<div style="max-height: 100px">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fixed">blah</td>
    <td class="not_fixed">blah!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

This is an example which demonstrates my issue much more clearly:

https://jsfiddle.net/YMvk9/6468/

Comment: You're shooting yourself in the foot trying to set an `absolute` element inside a `max-height` one. Try changing `absolute` to `relative`.

Comment: @DevlshOne: Then the first column won't be frozen. I think the author should look into pagination to accomplish what they want.

Comment: @im1dermike You're right, it won't be frozen. However, that first column is much taller than the 100px limit he placed on the rest of the table.

Comment: It's a booking system listing a huge amount of rooms (~90 rooms). Pagination doesn't make alot of sense in that context.

Comment: @DevlshOne: That's the point of his question...

Comment: @SeñorReginoldFrancis: Why not?